# This question, is it ok?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24871/primum-non-nocere

I would like to know if this question is acceptable, and if not, how it can be improved.

I'd prefer to have the feedback here and not on the question (Unless it organically appears due to users browsing of course) and have the chance to receive feedback and revise accordingly if it is deemed unacceptable and must be put on hold.

I do not want to do this with every question, just this question in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in my view, I would say:

1. I have some trouble grasping quite what is being asked.
2. There appear to be several questions there that are not merely restatements of each other (but again, see 1).
3. Possibly because I'm having trouble grasping the meaning of the question, it seems to invite discussion or opinions rather than being a Q&A answerable philosophical question.

To test your question on the third point, think of what a good answer to the question would be and whether it could address the philosophical problem you are facing.

If the answer does not result in single answer being able to give you a new way to look at the problem that makes it no longer a question, then it's not especially clear how the question can be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will revise tomorrow when I have time to see if I can tighten it up.

Comment: I've decided to delete the question as it is indeed to broad.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Virmaior's points:

Your question is more specific than "primum non nocere". The title could be a little more descriptive.

The question is fairly broad. It asks among other things for a list of theories, and in addition to that for every theory what any current society would have to change in order to adhere to that theory. Discussing only three types of societies and three theories, that's at least 9 paragraphs just for that part of your question. Questions should be answerable in a few paragraphs.